# Merged meshes, need to reapply the armature

Tags: mesh, armature, pose-mode

Blender newbie here. So here's what's going on.

I had an existing mesh and armature, I had to decimate it, which actually messed up the hands, no big deal, I just reimported another model, deleted this ones hands, and then attached new hands onto this model.

Now however, when I move the armature, it only moves the "previous" mesh (Even though I've merged the two meshes as 1.)

Is there anyway to "refresh" the armature, and apply it to the new hands. Here is a picture of what is occurring:

[image: Image 1]

Here is also an image of the hierarchy that may help:
[image: Hierarchy]

Comment: You need to recalculate the weight for the part of the mesh that you've just joined. To do that you can select the armature, shift select the mesh, switch it to Weight Paint mode, select the bones you want, shift left click to select several bones, go into the header menu > Weight and click on Assign Automatic from Bones

Comment: Thank you @moonboots

Alright so I tried these steps & unfortunately, I'm running into another problem I am receiving this error:
Bone Heat Weighting: Failed to find solution for one or more bones.

Comment: maybe share your file (remove all the useless objects): https://pasteall.org/blend/